# BigQuery Regex Replace only works when it has one character in pattern

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

For the below query (Standard SQL), it should remove all column names.

```
WITH table AS (SELECT "abc" aa, 0 b, NULL c, "xyz" d, 0 e, 0.0 f UNION ALL
               SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )
SELECT *,
REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[a-zA-Z0-9_]":', "") AS check 
FROM table t
```

But it only works when the column name is single character. It doesn't work for more than one character.
Need help on this

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT "abc" aa, 0 b, NULL c, "xyz" d, 0 e, 0.0 f UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL 
)
SELECT *, FORMAT('%t', t) AS check
FROM table t
```

with result

```
Row aa      b       c       d       e       f       check    
1   abc     0       null    xyz     0       0.0     (abc, 0, NULL, xyz, 0, 0.0)  
2   null    null    null    null    null    null    (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

If you want to have double quotes for values - use `FORMAT('%T', t)` so result will be like `("abc", 0, NULL, "xyz", 0, 0.0)`

Meantime, the simple fix was - `REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*":', "") AS check` - note added `*`

```
#standardSQL
WITH table AS (
  SELECT "abc" aa, 0 b, NULL c, "xyz" d, 0 e, 0.0 f UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL 
)
SELECT *, 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'"[a-zA-Z0-9_]*":', "") AS check 
FROM table t
```

with result

```
Row aa      b       c       d       e       f       check    
1   abc     0       null    xyz     0       0.0     {"abc",0,null,"xyz",0,0}     
2   null    null    null    null    null    null    {null,null,null,null,null,null}
```